# Google Chrome and Mac Localhost Issues

Tags: apache, google-chrome, localhost

Odd and annoying issue. I have Apache up and running on My mac and I'm utilizing the virtual hosts capability. Though oddly enough, whenever I type in the local site, in this case: local.511, it just goes to search. If I do http://local.511, it seemed to have work. Though only after doing it at least 15 times. Also, even after getting that to work, I still can't navigate to other pages by simply typing them in. IE: local.511/lalaal/page1.

It works fine in Safari and Firefox.

Any ideas for Chrome?

OSX 10.6
Chrome 10.0.648.151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a custom [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) then chrome will assume you want to do a search. You either have to use http://local.511 or change the 511 to something like .com, .net, .org etc and set up that domain in  your hosts file.

Edit:

Actually it seems you can just add a slash to the end of the url:

local.511/